# What is the most simple / lightest-weight WSGI framework?

Tags: python, frameworks, rack, wsgi, flask

Which of the [WSGI frameworks](http://www.wsgi.org/en/latest/frameworks.html) are super lightweight and minimal? If you are familar with ruby, then I'm looking for something similar to Rails Metal.

- WSGI == Rack
- Rails == Django
- Sinatra == Flask
- Rails Metal == ***???????***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) is what you're looking for.